# Katalon Recorder : If variable contains some text - True/False

Tags: if-statement, contains, katalon-recorder, katalon

In Katalon Chrome addon or Selenium Chrome addon, I'm trying to set up a simple check to verify if an element contains a specific text.

Here is what I've done so far :

**Katalon Recorder (Example):**

*Command | Target | Value*

click | id=subscribed |

StoreText | id=subscribed | i

echo | ${i}

verifyText | id=subscribed | *alyx*

**Log result :**

[info] Executing: | click | id=subscribed | |

[info] Executing: | storeText | id=subscribed | i |

[info] Store 'alyx.vance' into 'i'

[info] Executing: | echo | ${i} | |

[info] Expand variable '${i}' into 'alyx.vance'

[info] echo: alyx.vance

[info] Executing: | verifyText | id=subscribed | *alyx* |

**From here, how can I set up this? :**

If VerifyText = *alyx* (Contains) => Goto Label X (True)

If VerifyText != *alyx* (Not Contains) => Goto Label Y (False)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hello Matt, in the description I mentioned the code to be able to reproduce it but here it is not an issue, just a question to know how to do.
Any idea how I can set an action with a status (OK/NOK) behind "VerifyText"?

Answer (score 0):

I've finaly found the solution and it works that way on my script :

Command | Target | Value

click | id=subscribed

StoreText | id=subscribed | i

echo | ${i}

storeText | alyx.vance | j

if | ('${i}').includes('${j}')

gotoLabel | X

else

gotoLabel | Y

...

endif

It works for me but in certain cases, it might not work so, if you need help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
storeText | id=subscribed | i
store | alyx.vance | j
if | ${i} == ${j}
click | Label_X_locator
elseIf | ${i} != ${j}
click | Label_Y_locator
endIf
```